# C++ no match for 'operator=' (postfix to infix)

Tags: c++

I am writing this program that converts postfix to infix. 
I manage to code a program that does the opposite but when I try to create this particular program I have encountered many issues that I can't really understand what I am doing wrong.

The following is my program:
I can't get it to compile. in my mind, it is a simple problem but I just can't figure out the issue.

```
/*
 * crate function toInfix
 * create empty stack
 * initialize output, and operand1 and operand2 variables strings
 * for loop entired input
 * if input is operator
 * pop thwo operands from the stack
 * combine the two operands with the operator in between
 * push the new expression on the stack
 * if input is operand then push in the stack
 */

string toInfix(string input)
{
    stack <char> stk;
    string output, oprnd1, oprnd2;
    for(auto& in : input)
    {
        if(isSymbol(in))
        {
            oprnd1 = stk.pop();
            oprnd2 = stk.pop();
            output = oprnd1 + in + oprnd2;
            stk.push(output);
        }
        stk.push(in);
    }
    while(!stk.empty())
    {
        output = stk.pop();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the signature for `std::stack::pop`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley i have tried changing `oprnd1 = stk.pop();
            oprnd2 = stk.pop();` to `oprnd1 = stk.top();
            oprnd2 = stk.top();` and poping the stack respectively,  i still cant figure it out T_T

Comment: Okay, but have you looked at the signature of `std::stack::pop`? Do you know what I mean by signature?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I guess i do not.

Comment: The signature is the return type, the name of the function, and the parameters. In this case, `void pop();` -- Given that, what do you expect `output = stk.pop();` to do?

Comment: well I just expect it to pop everything that is left in the stack to return it later on.   something like this `while(!stk.empty()) { output+= stk.top(); stk.pop(); } return output;`

Comment: That's an awfully strange thing to expect. `std::stack::pop` doesn't return anything. So `output = stk.pop()` doesn't make sense, and is the cause of your compiler error. You've already shown you know how to correctly extract the top element in that loop you just showed, so why aren't you just doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106184/discussion-between-guille-and-benjamin-lindley).

Comment: Please don't change the question. If you are stuck on another issue, besides the `operator=` issue, ask a new question specifically for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Benjamin said, `pop` returns void. Therefore, setting a string to void is not possible. To fix this, set it equal to the top element, and then pop it.

```
output += stk.top();
stk.pop();
```

Comment: if you try to compile the code above you will see i get the following error: `no matching function for call to 'std::stack<char>::push(std::string&)`  `stk.push(output);`

Comment: It's because you're trying to push a string into a character stack.

Comment: i figured that much.. but how can I fix it then? i beeing trying to figure that out the whole night and tried different things but it just gets worse T_T

Comment: I can't really tell you how to fix it without re writing your whole  program. Some advice - you said that you wrote an infix to postfix program. Try to reverse what you did in that program.

Comment: that is what i have been trying to do this whole time.. but based on your feedback, is my postfix to infix program completely wrong?

Comment: Your program isn't completely wrong, but if it was me writing this program, I would rewrite it.  That's just how I do things though. Have you tried to Google other solutions and work off of that? I always find that helpful.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to see if I could do it my way :( disappointed though :(

Comment: try std::foreach(output.begin(), output.end(), [&](char c){stk.push(c);}); to push on to the stack, or write your own stack class based on a std::string